# Segmentation fault when assigning pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have

```
struct Node{
    Node* father;
    Node* left_son;
    Node* right_son;
    char content;
};

void build_tree(Node* node){
    Node* left;
    left->father=node; //segfault
}

void init(){
    Node* root;
    build_tree(root);
}
```

I am getting segfault in `build_tree()`. Why?

Comment: have you heard about operator `new`?

Comment: Oh, i completely missed that one. Am a bit rusty in C++ :)

Comment: Can you please just make an effort to read a C++ book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Node* left;
```

This *just* declares a pointer. Nothing else. There is no `Node` object. The pointer can point at a `Node` object but it doesn't automatically give you one. As it is, `left` is uninitialized and cannot be dereferenced without invoking undefined behaviour.

You need to allocate a `Node` object in some way, perhaps with `new`:

```
Node* left = new Node();
```

But then make sure you don't forget to also `delete` it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't initialize `left`, so it points to a seemingly random location. Dereferencing random pointers causes *undefined behavior*, which often leads to crashes.

The same applies for `root` in the `main` function.

You need to allocate nodes before using them.

Answer (score 2):

The left in the function of `bulid_tree()` haven't been assigned a valid value before you use it to point to the father.

I don't know what the `build_tree()` is used for. But just to solve this problem, you change the code to this:

```
void build_tree(Node* node)
{
    Node * left = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    left->father=node;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

segmentation fault generally occurs when there is a instruction that tries to access a invalid/incorrect memory address.

in your function :
    void build_tree(Node* node)
    {

```
Node* left;
```

-- this creates a pointer which is not initialised to point to some object that should exist.

```
left->father=node; //segfault
```

-- here you are trying to access the member of the object that the pointer has been initialised to , but in reality the object dosent exist (no new - constructor statement is present) hence the access is a invalid access resulting in a segmentation fault.

```
}
```

to correct the above , as one of the SO member (sftrabbit) had answered previously you would need to add the following statement before the pointer initialisation ::
    Node* left = new Node();

thats all. 
hope this helps